# req.session em node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, back-end

Gostaria de saber como é o funcionamento básico da estrutura req.session do Node.js. Ela é nativa do Express ou do express-session? Por favor, me ajudem a entender mais sobre sessões.

Answer (score 2):

ela é instalada à parte usando o comando "npm install express-session --save"

depois coloque isso no seu arquivo principal:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: '2C44-4D44-WppQ38S',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

E para criar um nova variável de sessão, segue o exemplo:

```
req.session.usuario = usuario;
```

E um middleware básico para autenticar seria:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.usuario) {
      return res.redirect('/');
  }
    return next();
};
```

Comment: Eu andei dando uma pesquisada e consegui entender, valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Ela não é nativa do express, é necessário instalar ela pelo

**NPM:** `npm i express-session`

ou

**Yarn:** `yarn add express-session`

Até onde eu sei ela é uma forma mais segura de guardar informações que precisam ser protegidas, como um token gerado pelo jwt.

O express session é um middleware que precisa ser chamado no seu arquivo principal desta forma:

```
const serverSession = require('express-session')


.use(serverSession({ secret: sua-chave-secreta, resave: false, saveUninitialized:false }))
```

A sua chave secreta precisa ser gerada a md5 se não me engano e guardada de forma segura.

Leia a documentação pra entender de forma correta como a mesma funciona [documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Espero ter ajudado.